# How to add the index value of two array in java using for loop

Tags: java, arrays

Hello I need a little help here I'm having trouble with my logic mind I'm stuck with this code :

```
public class March22Arrayloop {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] anArray1 = { 10, 20, 8, 150, 300 };
        int[] anArray2 = { 205, 20, 30, 50, 80 };
        int result;


        for (int i = 0; i < anArray1.lenght; i++) {

            result = anArray1[i] + anArray2[i];
            System.out.print(result + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

which is wrong

I am trying to add the value inside the index of my two arrays.. (you got me?)

using for loop, but the problem is I am having a problem with logic at for loop and the item inside the for loop, the value I want to add is at the top those things is a I want to add 1 by 1 .. and it will display like

Output must be :

```
10 + 205 = (the sum)

20 + 20  = (the sum)
```

(and so on)

how to do this?       advance thanks

Comment: Like `System.out.println(""+anArray1[i]+" + "+anArray2[i] + " = "+result);`?

Comment: Hint: if you use `System.out.println`(print**ln**) you don't need to add the linebreak at the end of your string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Independent of what you actually want (which is a puzzle for me), something from this should be it:

In simple terms, loop through all indices of the array until **either** array's length is reached.
Get the sum of the two elements, add that to the totalResult and print some stuff on each iteration.

At the end, a simple println (which automatically adds the "\n" at the end) shows the totalResult.

Be very careful, as the println in the loop adds the integers to strings, which turns them into strings. That is why they are displayed as individual numbers, if you only display the numbers, it will display the sum instead of the individual numbers.

```
    int [] anArray1 = {10,20,8,150,300};
    int [] anArray2 = {205,20,30,50,80};
    int totalResult = 0;

    for (int i=0; i < anArray1.length && i < anArray2.length; i++)
    {
        int result = anArray1[i]+anArray2[i];
        totalResult += result;
        System.out.println(anArray1[i] + " + " + anArray2[i] + " = " + result);
    }
    System.out.println("Total = " + totalResult);
```

I suppose your teacher would be proud ;)

Comment: maaaaaaaaaaaaaaaan!! you just save my daaayy!!!!! thanksss ^^ He will hahaha really thank you man.. i want to ask what is the purpose if += ? why not putting just = or + just wondering? ..

Comment: += is for making it easier to understand (assuming you know the operator).   "a += 3;" essentially is the same as "a = a + 3;"

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.print(""+anArray1[i]+" + "+anArray2[i] +" = " + (anArray1[i]+anArray2[i]))
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.printf("%d + %d = %d", anArray1[i], anArray2[i], result);
```

For more help check this tutorial: [Formatting Numeric Print Output](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html)

Answer (score 0):

Change the print line like below

```
 System.out.print(anArray1[i]+" + " + anArray2[i] + " = " + result+"\n");
```